# Manager for a user profile to create and delete both user and the profile

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-contrib

I have a model called `Personnel` which I'm using as the profile model for the `User` model. Moderators on my site can create and their own accounts but all the profile fields should be filled in. Here's my model

```
class Personnel(models.Model):
    """
    Model for storing the personnel information
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        null=False, max_length=50, verbose_name="Phone"
    )
    address = models.CharField(
        null=True, max_length=500, verbose_name="Address"
    )
```

I need to implement the following.

A `create` method on the `Personnel` model so that when someone invokes the method `Personnel.objects.create(username, email, phone, address)`, it creates a new user in the `User` model and also stores the profile fields in the `Personnel` model. I would need a form for this to handle the request but this form should validate both the fields of the `Personnel` model and the `User` model.

An `delete` method on the `Personnel` model so that when someone invokes the method `Personnel.objects.delete(username)`, it deletes the profile from the `Personnel` model and the user from the `User` model. I don't think I need a form for this.

Could anyone please tell me how to do the form bit and the manager bit. Here's what I have so far:

Form:

?

Manager:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Personnel(models.Manager):
    """
    This is the manager for the Personnel model. It contains the logic for
    creating a new personnel which also creates a new User.
    """
    def create(self, username, email, phone, address):
        """
        Creates a new personnel
        """
        pass

    def delete(self, username):
        """
        Deletes a personnel
        """
        super(Personnel, self).delete()
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PersonnelManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, username, email, phone, address, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, email=email)
        return super(PersonnelManager, self).create(user=user, phone=phone, address=address, **kwargs)

class Personnel(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = PersonnelManager()
```

Deleting should take care of itself through the cascade.

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how I would go about the form. I would have like to have a common form to validate my `Personnel` mode and the `User` model. The `User` form is at `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`. Would I need to copy-paste the code from that into my custom form?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier to add methods to `Personnel.save()` and `Personnel.delete()` to do this work.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

The Personnel.save() is called by Django and can create a missing  User and Profile.

The "Overriding Delete" sidebar may not be relevant, depending on your application. Bulk deletes are rare and it's easy to do a post-bulk-delete cleanup.  Or do individual deletes instead of a bulk delete.